# Idhttp Indy upload to Dropbox with utf-8 file name

Tags: delphi, dropbox, indy, delphi-2009, indy10

I'm trying to upload a file to Dropbox using Indy 10 and XE8. While file name like 'file.txt' it works OK, but with 'файл.txt' or so, I have '????.txt' on DropBox. I read about parameters with utf-8 but it is don't work with headers :-(.

How can I upload a file and save utf-8 file name?

```
procedure TSaveFilterForm.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  URL = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source: TFileStream;
  Res: String;
begin                           
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + AccessToken;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';
    Source := TFileStream.Create('c:\test.txt', fmOpenRead);

    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Dropbox-API-Arg'] :=
      Format('{ "path": "%s", "mode": "overwrite"}',
        ['/файл.txt']); // Dropbox => ????.txt
    try
      Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
    finally
      Source.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these calls with the parameters in the header, you need to escape these characters. That is, when you use the “Dropbox-API-Arg” header, you need to make it “HTTP header safe”. This means using JSON-style “\uXXXX” escape codes for the character 0x7F and all non-ASCII characters.

Some, but not all, languages/libraries do this for you. For example, for JavaScript, to do this yourself you could do something like this:

```
var charsToEncode = /[\u007f-\uffff]/g;

function http_header_safe_json(v) {
 return JSON.stringify(v).replace(charsToEncode,
 function(c) {
 return '\\u' + ('000' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
 }
 );
}
```

and then something like:

```
'Dropbox-API-Arg': http_header_safe_json({ path: dropboxFilePath })
```

It sounds like your platform doesn't do that for you, so you'll want to implement this in your code.

Comment: [Delphi has its own JSON library](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON).

Comment: @Greg thanks. I have found such solution for delphi - http://drcooper.livejournal.com/4186.html.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP headers cannot contain non-ASCII characters, not even UTF-8.  If you need to send non-ASCII characters in an HTTP header, they must be encoded in an ASCII-compatible format.

In this case, since the header in question contains JSON, you can use JSON's own `\uXXXX` syntax for encoding non-ASCII characters:

> Any code point may be represented as a hexadecimal number. The meaning of such a number is determined by ISO/IEC 10646. If the code point is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, followed by the lowercase letter u, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the code point. Hexadecimal digits can be digits (U+0030 through U+0039) or the hexadecimal letters A through F in uppercase (U+0041 through U+0046) or lowercase (U+0061 through U+0066). So, for example, a string containing only a single reverse solidus character may be represented as "`\u005C`".

For example:

```
procedure TSaveFilterForm.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  URL = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Source: TFileStream;
  Res: String;
begin                           
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + AccessToken;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';

    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Dropbox-API-Arg'] := Format(
      '{ "path": "%s", "mode": "overwrite"}',
      ['/\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043B.txt']
    );

    Source := TFileStream.Create('c:\test.txt', fmOpenRead);
    try
      Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source);
      // alternatively, without using TFileStream manually:
      // Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, 'C:\test.txt');
    finally
      Source.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I suggest you use a JSON library to create the JSON content.  For instance, you can use Delphi's own [JSON framework](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/JSON) in Delphi 2010 and later, eg:

```
uses
  ...,
  // use DBXJSON in D2010-XE
  // use Data.DBXJSON in XE2-XE5
  // use System.JSON in XE6+
  ;

procedure TSaveFilterForm.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  URL = 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload';
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Json: TJSONObject;
  Res: String;
begin                           
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
    IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
    IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
    IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + AccessToken;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/octet-stream';

    Json := TJSONObject.Create;
    try
      Json.AddPair('path', '/файл.txt');
      Json.AddPair('mode', 'overwrite');
      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Dropbox-API-Arg'] := Json.ToJSON;
    finally
      Json.Free;
    end;

    Res := IdHTTP.Post(URL, 'C:\test.txt');
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

There are plenty of 3rd party JSON libraries available for Delphi, if you need to support other Delphi versions.

Comment: thanks. With \uXXXX it works fine. 
I didn't try TJSONObject, because D2009 hasn't it.

Comment: @OlegAdibekov there are plenty of 3rd party JSON libraries available for Delphi that support 2009.

Comment: I use LkJSON, @RemyLebeau. But in this case it will be too many $IFDEF. 1. DXE6+ + JSON; 2. D2010+ + DBXJSON; 3. D2009 (utf-8) + LkJSON; 4. Old (Ansi) Delphi + LkJSON. Too complicated.

Comment: @OlegAdibekov: Or, you could just pick one JSON library that works on all versions. LkJSON can be used in versions newer than D2009, after all. You don't *HAVE* to use Embarcadero's JSON library.

Comment: I tried LkJSON and it works OK with XE8 (after changing String -> AnsiString etc.). But  JSON placed in specifications.